# Mechanize breaks on ASP page

Tags: ruby, mechanize

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new
login = agent.get('http://www.schoolnet.ch/DE/HomeDE.htm')
agent.click login.link_with text: /Login/
```

And I get `Mechanize::UnsupportedSchemeError`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mechanize did'nt support javascript but you can add search field to the form assign search term to it and submit the form using mechanize

```
form = page.forms.first
form.add_field! "Field_name here","BotM$ucUser$ucUser2Col$cmdLogin"
page = form.submit
```

Comment: can you comment further about what this does?

Comment: for future reference, the field names i had to set for a WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions were "__EVENTTARGET" and "__EVENTVALUE".  So it looked like: `f.add_field! "__EVENTTARGET","dnn$ctr409$ManageUsers$Password$cmdUpdate"` and 
        `f.add_field! "__EVENTARGUMENT",""`

Answer (score 1):

The link in question runs a javascript function.

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('BotM$ucUser$ucUser2Col$cmdLogin','')" id="BotM_ucUser_ucUser2Col_cmdLogin">Login</a>
```

Mechanize doesn't support javascript links. Someone else suggests using Harmony.

Check https://github.com/mynyml/harmony